# Complementing JUnit test batteries with dynamic JVM languages

Tags: java, groovy, clojure, junit, rhino

**I want to begin porting a series of verbose unit tests (big jsons, not embeddable in standard Java, lots of bean field checking) into a more expressive language (like Clojure,  Groovy, Jython).**

Languages which should be able to compliment standard Java source code are, from my experience, Clojure and Groovy. Possibly the Rhino or BeanShell could be used here, but I have no experience with these...

Any other suggestions would be welcome :

My requirements are :

1) The language must run, as is, in the same environment as my Java EE code.

2) The language must be able to embed large, multi line text in strings.

3) The language's unit tests must be run natively as normal JUnit tests by the ANT and Maven junit tasks/goals.

4) The language's unit tests must be able to call regular code and work with dependencies  in my source code base (i.e. it must have access to the classes on my classpath that my regular junit test package does) natively, with no issues.

**My questions :**

1) Is it possible to write source code in one language, while also writing junit tests in another junit language, and if so, are there any examples of this?

2) If yes, what language(s) best satisfy 1-3 above.

Also, any *meaningful* commentary on the merits of this "write in java, junit tests in *" proposal would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I was once looking for a testing library that meets the same requirements and some more like

- same framework from unit testing, integration testing and end-to-end testing
- simplified and intuitive data-driven testing
- BDD kind of testing
- Transition should be progressive (i.e. we are a java shop and if someone doesn't want to take advantage of groovy, they can still use Java)

And [spock](http://code.google.com/p/spock/) is a powerful framework that meets all of the requirements. We can mix both JUNIT and Spock together. Spock generates the reports in the same format as Junit etc.

**Examples**

1. integration testing: Spock Grails, Spring and Unitils plugin
2. end-to-end ui testing: [Geb](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/testing.html#spock_junit__testng) + Spock
3. end-to-end app to app interfaces like webservices etc: [HttpBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/) + http://groovy.codehaus.org/GroovyWS + Spock

Comment: very, very cool.  any examples of a real heterogenous testing using spock, junit, etc... ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using an IDE? If so, then sorry to be a boring old fart, but i would suggest keeping your tests in Java.

The reason for this is that IDEs, in my experience, have no or poor support for working with heterogeneous codebases. Think about renaming a method in your application code. With any decent IDE, you do this as a refactoring, and all call sites in Java code get changed to reflect the new name. However, call sites in other languages will not (as far as i know). If your tests are in something other than Java, that means you now have a pile of broken tests to find and fix. Just because you renamed a method! Many kinds of refactorings will raise this problem. You may also suffer from an inability to use a debugger on your test and application code together, to run code coverage analysis, or to do various other useful things.

Using an untyped language, like Javascript, or Groovy as it is usually used, also inherently means that your tests can't make assertions about types, and so can't test the full range of things that can go wrong in Java. For example, in a Java test, i can write:

```
List<CharSequence> words = foo.getWords();
```

And for that test to even compile, `getWords` has to return a `List<CharSequence>`. If someone changes it to a `List<String>`, the test breaks. That lets you use the test to enforce the design of an API.

Another approach, then, might be to use Java, and to find ways to deal with large strings, and large bean comparisons.

The easiest way to deal with large strings is probably to push them out into individual text files which are classpath resources. You can then write a simple utility method to load a named resource, and read it into a string.

I don't know exactly what your "lots of bean field checking" involves, but if it's checking the values in fields of beans, perhaps deeply nested, then some simple utility methods could help a lot. Perhaps you could read specifications of fields and their expected values from properties files, and reflectively extract and check them?

Comment: @Pangea: Are there IDEs which will carry Java refactorings across into Groovy code? That's what's relevant here.

Comment: IntelliJ can refactor across Groovy and Java

Answer (score 2):

I write a lot of tests in [easyb](http://www.easyb.org/), a Groovy-based BDD language. JRuby and RSpec is another great option. Why is there a requirement that the tests be run "as JUnit tests", and what exactly does it mean?

If that's an actual requirement, you limit in the expressiveness of your tests (I'm not a big fan of JBehave). Groovy is my language of choice when doing a Java + real language project, although I use JRuby for command-line interfaces to the app.

Groovy's annotation support is top-notch and seamless, IMO it's a no-brainer choice for ease of adoption for writing JUnit tests, more or less as you'd write them in Java, but in Groovy.

Comment: My project is 100% java.  Im only adding the dynamic language support because I want dynamic languages for some unit tests, because I think they will be easier to write, because I want full multiline string declarations.  Also, Its a nice way to slowly introduce some dynamic code into the code base, which is a long term goal.   Does that clarify ?

Comment: @jayunit100 No; it doesn't really address the question--I'm asking why you specifically want only JUnit tests.

Comment: Well - as long as the build fails when the test fails, i dont really care if they are junit.  Seems like junit would be tightly integrated with my meta-build stuff (for example, printing out the failures, writing the results to xml,... thats all automated the same way with junit).   id like to leverage the existing framework, but just write tests with nicer syntax, rather then having two testing frameworks.  Im afraid of too many moving parts here.

Comment: @jayunit100 Most have [Maven integration](http://www.easyb.org/running.html#maven). Plus the output is human-readable, and easyb skeletons can be written by stakeholders. We had to tweak to get the output visible in our CI server. Sticking to only one testing framework *greatly* limits your flexibility, particularly when you move beyond unit testing.

Comment: Good points... Thanks very helpful ... What do you mean "beyond" ? Junit can do integration tests to... What type of limitations are you talking about?